# How to get summary based on financial year using Telerik pivot grid

Tags: asp.net, telerik

We're using Telerik asp.net controls in one of our old projects (but it's using the latest version of telerik).

All summaries in the PivotGrid are based on the calendar year (starting from January) and we need to change it to arbitrary financial year (say starting from July).

So for example a summary of Q1 in 2016 should be from Jul to Sep instead of Jan to Mar.

Is there any way to customize the Telerik PivotGrid to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a research on this problem and realized that Telerik Pivot Grid doesn't have such a feature so I handled the required business logic in the data tier.

I've looked into Telerik docs in depth and I'm pretty sure that it doesn't have such a feature (so far) and there is no way to handle in the PivotGrid control.